# mocking database in derived class

Tags: php, testing, mocking, phpspec

I've got Repository classes which implement a specific interface and also extend a base class for the specific database.

base class:

```
abstract class CouchDB
{
  protected $db;

  public function __construct(Sag $db)
  {
    $this->db = $db;
  }

  private function call_get($url) {...} //this is a wrapper for $db->get()
}
```

derived class:

```
class CouchExpression extends CouchDB implements ExpressionInterface
{
  public function __construct(Sag $db)
  {
    parent::__construct($db);
  }
}
```

the spec:

```
class CouchExpressionSpec extends ObjectBehavior
{
  public function let($db)
  {
    $db->beADoubleOf('\Sag');

    $this->beConstructedWith($db);
  }

  public function it_gets_returned_by_its_id()
  {
     $this->db->get('...')->willReturn([]);
  }
}
```

When running PHPSpec I get: `property db not found`
Is there a way to fix this other than setting the property to `public`?

After setting it to `public`I get: `call to a member function willReturn() on a non-object.`
So I can't run `->willReturn()` on `$this->db`

But why? When doing this in the `let`method of the test it works. But not all tests do need the same data returned...

How do I get this running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare your double without the explicit call, like this:

```
function let(\Sag $db)
{
    $this->beConstructedWith($db);
}
```

Having done this, if you pass a property of the same name to your example, it will be the same instance of the double:

```
function it_gets_returned_by_its_id($db)
{
    $db->get('...')->willReturn([]);
}
```

Also, by convention let and example methods don't use the public keyword, they'll be public anyway and it reduces noise around your examples.